# Selenium multiple desired capabilities settings

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set multiple desired capability,for an instance of a chrome driver object in selenium.
I would like the browser to first 
set the download location of files, then to disable the pdf viewer plugin in Chrome browser. Can anyone assist?

Code snippet for disabling PDF viewer plugin:

```
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    Map<String, Object> preferences = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    preferences.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[] { "Chrome PDF Viewer" });
    ChromeOptions options1 = new ChromeOptions();
    options1.setExperimentalOption("prefs", preferences);
    caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options1);
```

Code snippet for setting the download location:

```
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("download.default_directory", "C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking. Please read [ask]. If you aren't familiar with English consider using Google Translator.

Comment: i am trying to set multiple desired capabilities for an instance of chrome driver. i would like to set the chrome browser  download location and also to disable the PDF viewer in the browser instance.

Comment: Post the code you have tried.

Comment: DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
  
  Map<String, Object> preferences = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  preferences.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[] {
       "Chrome PDF Viewer"
   });

       
  ChromeOptions options1 = new ChromeOptions();
  
     options1.setExperimentalOption("prefs", preferences);

        caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options1);

Comment: Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  prefs.put("download.default_directory", "C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
  caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

Comment: i have those two code in my program. the first one is for the PDF disable and the second one is for the chrome download settings

Answer (score 0):

Don't create two separate ChromeOptions just because you want multiple capabilities. That's why they take maps. Just put both key value pairs in a single map and then add that to the options object ... eg:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
Map<String, Object> preferences = new HashMap<>();
preferences.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[] { "Chrome PDF Viewer" });
preferences.put("download.default_directory", "C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", preferences);
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```